# C linked list - when to free allocated memory

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, malloc, free

I have a simple linked list implementation with push, pop, unshift and shift functions to add/remove data as required.  I would like to ensure that my implementation is not leaking memory when retrieving data via calls to pop and shift.

How do I go about freeing memory which has been allocated via malloc, while also returning the data to the caller?

### list.h

```
typedef struct _list_cell_t {
    void *data;
    struct _list_cell_t *next;
} list_cell_t;

typedef struct _list_cell_t *list_cell_ptr;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    list_cell_ptr head;
} list_t;

void list_init(list_t *p_list);
void list_free(list_t *p_list);

void list_push(list_t *p_list, void *data);
void list_unshift(list_t *p_list, void *data);

void *list_pop(list_t *p_list);
void *list_shift(list_t *p_list);
```

---

### list.c

```
#include "list.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void list_init(list_t *p_list)
{
    memset(p_list, 0, sizeof(list_t));

    p_list->head = NULL;
    p_list->size = 0;
}

void list_free(list_t *p_list)
{
    list_cell_ptr p_cell, p_next;

    p_cell = p_list->head;
    while (p_cell != NULL) {
        p_next = p_cell->next;
        memset(p_cell, 0, sizeof(list_cell_t));
        free(p_cell);
        p_cell = p_next;
    }

    memset(p_list, 0, sizeof(list_t));
}

void list_push(list_t *p_list, void *data)
{
    list_cell_ptr *p_curr_ptr, p_tmp;

    p_tmp = (list_cell_ptr)malloc(sizeof(list_cell_t));
    memset(p_tmp, 0, sizeof(list_cell_t));
    p_tmp->data = data;

    p_curr_ptr = &(p_list->head);
    while (*p_curr_ptr != NULL) {
        p_curr_ptr = &((*p_curr_ptr)->next);
    }

    p_tmp->next = NULL;
    *p_curr_ptr = p_tmp;
    p_list->size++;
}

void list_unshift(list_t *p_list, void *data)
{
    list_cell_ptr *p_curr_ptr, p_tmp;

    p_tmp = (list_cell_ptr)malloc(sizeof(list_cell_t));
    memset(p_tmp, 0, sizeof(list_cell_t));
    p_tmp->data = data;

    p_curr_ptr = &(p_list->head);

    p_tmp->next = *p_curr_ptr;
    *p_curr_ptr = p_tmp;
    p_list->size++;
}

void *list_pop(list_t *p_list)
{
    list_cell_ptr *p_curr_ptr = &(p_list->head);

    while ((*p_curr_ptr)->next != NULL) {
        p_curr_ptr = &((*p_curr_ptr)->next);
    }

    void *ret = (*p_curr_ptr)->data;

    *p_curr_ptr = NULL;
    p_list->size--;
    return ret;
}

void *list_shift(list_t *p_list)
{
    void *ret = p_list->head->data;

    list_cell_ptr p_next = p_list->head->next;

    p_list->head = p_next;
    p_list->size--;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Without the typedefs, the excessive parenthesis, the casts of malloc(), and the listhead pointer, this code could be simple and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I go about freeing memory which has been allocated via malloc, while also returning the data to the caller?

Overall, the general rule in C memory management is that it must always be clear where the responsibility lies for freeing every piece of dynamically allocated memory, and wherever it does lie, that code must take care to fulfill all such responsibilities without fail.  In your case, the only reasonable place to put the responsibility for freeing the `struct _list_cell_t` objects allocated for a given list is in the code that removes those objects from the list again (the `pop`, `shift`, and `free` functions).

After you free each such object, however, you must not access it again, so you must first store the `data` pointer you intend to return in a local variable.  In fact, you already do this.

There are lots of ways to implement the details, but I suggest this paradigm:

1. Store a pointer to the no-longer-needed `struct _list_cell_t` in a local variable.
2. Update the structure of the list to cut out that object.
3. Store a pointer to the wanted data in a local variable.
4. Free the unneeded `struct _list_cell_t` via the pointer recorded in step (1)
5. Return the data

Answer (score 1):

You should free the memeory using the pointer you have so before overwriting the value and loose the adresse that you point to. you have use that pointer to free the memory space.

```
void *list_pop(list_t *p_list)
{
    list_cell_ptr *p_curr_ptr = &(p_list->head);

    while ((*p_curr_ptr)->next != NULL) {
        p_curr_ptr = &((*p_curr_ptr)->next);
    }

    void *ret = (*p_curr_ptr)->data;
    free(*p_curr_ptr); //free memory
    *p_curr_ptr = NULL;

    p_list->size--;
    return ret;
}

void *list_shift(list_t *p_list)
{
    void *ret = p_list->head->data;

    list_cell_ptr p_next = p_list->head->next;
    free(p_list->head); //use this to free memory
    p_list->head = p_next;
    p_list->size--;

    return ret;
}
```

I hope that I answered your question

Answer (score -1):

You could use smart pointers.

This can be done using a struct in C.  I've included a basic example of this in C. It does not implement all the functions you have (just push and pop) but it should give you an idea of smart pointers.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// the client get's a pointer to this struct NOT the listitem
struct data
{
    int ref_count;
    int *data;
};

// this is only used by the main, push and pop functions
struct listitem
{
    struct listitem *next;
    struct data *the_data;
};

// the client will have to use decrement() when it is finished with the data
int decrement(struct data *list_data)
{
    if(list_data->ref_count > 0)
        list_data->ref_count--;
    if (list_data->ref_count == 0 && list_data->data)
    {
        free(list_data->data);
        list_data->data = 0;
        free(list_data);
        return 0;
    }
    return(list_data->ref_count);
}

// the client can use increment() if it passes the data to another variable
struct data *increment(struct data *list_data)
{
    if (list_data)
        list_data->ref_count++;
    return(list_data);
}

void free_list(struct listitem **pp)
{
    while (*pp)
    {
        struct listitem *temp = (*pp)->next;
        decrement((*pp)->the_data);
        free(*pp);
        (*pp) = temp;
    }
}

void push_list(struct listitem **pp, int *data)
{
    struct listitem *temp = (struct listitem *)malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
    temp->next = (*pp);
    (*pp) = temp;
    temp->the_data = (struct data *)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    temp->the_data->data = data;
    temp->the_data->ref_count = 1;
}

struct data *pop_list(struct listitem **pp)
{
    if (*pp)
    {
        struct listitem *temp = (*pp)->next;
        struct data *d = (*pp)->the_data;
        free(*pp);
        (*pp) = temp;
        return(d); // the data is not being freed from memory here
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct listitem *list = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int *pi = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        (*pi) = rand();
        push_list(&list, (int *)pi);
    }
    struct data *d[5];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        d[i] = pop_list(&list);
    free_list(&list); // the linked list has been destroyed now

    // this would be the client code
    struct data *d2 = increment(d[0]);

    struct data *d3 = increment(d[1]);

    // clean up, delete all but d2 and d3
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        decrement(d[i]);

    // do something with d2(d[0]) and d3(d[1])

    // clean up time
    decrement(d2); // now this data has been deleted
    decrement(d3); // now this data has been deleted

    return 0;
}
```

There's really no other way to share memory between your code and the client.

Comment: All he needs is a function which decrements the count on references to the struct and when count == 0 then free(struct) and data if applicable.

Comment: If that function is not called *automatically* by the system, then the result is not a smart pointer.  And setting up and using a manual mechanism along those lines would be way overkill for a situation such as the OP's.

Comment: Yes, it would not be automatically called.  It would work just like obj->Release() does in Component Object Model.

Comment: So your suggestion is to implement an auxiliary data structure and function library *inspired by* smart pointer techniques, and to use it manually?  That's a far cry from what your answer actually says.  It's also crazy overkill.